# How can I get a list of the fluent-bit inputs supported in my system?

Tags: fluentd

I've tried to use the `cpu` plugin and it says that `'cpu' tried to instance a plugin name that don't exists`. I know that not all inputs are supported on every operating system but how can I guest a list of the inputs for the system I'm currently on?

```
fluent-bit -i cpu -o stdout -vv

Fluent Bit v2.2.0
* Copyright (C) 2015-2023 The Fluent Bit Authors
* Fluent Bit is a CNCF sub-project under the umbrella of Fluentd
* https://fluentbit.io

[2023/12/08 08:35:37] [error] [config] section 'cpu' tried to instance a plugin name that don't exists
[2023/12/08 08:35:37] [error] configuration file contains errors, aborting.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `fluent-bit --help` and scroll down to the section `Inputs` which will list all the inputs

For example in macOS:

```
fluent-bit --help
Usage: fluent-bit [OPTION]

Available Options
... 
Inputs
  node_exporter_metrics   Node Exporter Metrics (Prometheus Compatible)
  kubernetes_events       Kubernetes Events
  kafka                   Kafka consumer input plugin
  fluentbit_metrics       Fluent Bit internal metrics
  prometheus_scrape       Scrape metrics from Prometheus Endpoint
  tail                    Tail files
  dummy                   Generate dummy data
  head                    Head Input
  health                  Check TCP server health
  http                    HTTP
  collectd                collectd input plugin
  statsd                  StatsD input plugin
  opentelemetry           OpenTelemetry
  elasticsearch           HTTP Endpoints for Elasticsearch (Bulk API)
  splunk                  Input plugin for Splunk HEC payloads
  event_test              Event tests for input plugins
  event_type              Event tests for input plugins
  nginx_metrics           Nginx status metrics
  serial                  Serial input
  stdin                   Standard Input
  syslog                  Syslog
  exec                    Exec Input
  udp                     UDP
  exec_wasi               Exec WASI Input
  tcp                     TCP
  mqtt                    MQTT, listen for Publish messages
  forward                 Fluentd in-forward
  random                  Random
```

that shows that `cpu` is not supported.